# D: crossplatform way to move to top level of path?

Tags: path, d

I have got path in variable like:

`D:\foo\bar\baz\file.txt`

It can be also like:

`/foo/bar/baz/file.txt`

I need way to cross-platform may to move to `bar` directory.

I found only one way, but it's look like hack:

`writeln(mystr.replaceLast("baz" ~ dirSeparator ~ "file.txt", ""));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std.path`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_path.html) has 2 functions for this: [`buildNormalizedPath`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_path.html#.buildNormalizedPath) and [`asNormalizedPath`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_path.html#.asNormalizedPath).

The only difference between them is that `asNormalizedPath` won't allocate memory.

Comment: Thank! Look like ```string path2 = buildNormalizedPath(path1, `..\..`);``` work for me.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason dpaste using dmd 2.068.2 isn't too happy about this. But it is correct code.

```
import std.path;
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    version(Posix) {
        writeln(buildNormalizedPath("/a/b/c", "../d"));
    } else version(Windows) {
        writeln(buildNormalizedPath("c:\\\\a\\b\\c", "..\\d"));
    }
}
```